# Python- Generate schema from file using TableSchema

Tags: python

I am trying to generate a schema from a csv file using TableSchame package.

```
def main():
        cls = '/Users//Downloads/s3_03b8a5f1-eddc-4ac5-9d72-.csv'
        with open(cls, "rb") as f:
             df= csv.reader(f)

        table= Table(df)
        table.infer(limit=500, confidence=0.55)
```

Gives me "raise exceptions.SourceError(message)
tabulator.exceptions.SourceError: Only callable returning an iterator is supported"

How do i get the Table to work with a csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table` can be used by directly passing the CSV file path, see the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/tableschema/):

```py
table= Table(cls)
```